# Cannot access REST endpoint in docker container from another docker container

Tags: rest, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have 2 microservices, each one deployed in its own docker container.
I use docker compose in order to deploy them and make microservice1 aware of microservice2. Each one is build in its own maven project.

Both microservices are deployed successfully, the docker containers are created and started and I can access each base root endpoint.

***The issue is that from microservice1, I want to access trough /remote url the base root from microservice2. This does not work and I get 404 when the call reaches the REST client that makes the get call to microservice2 which is in the `remote()` method bellow, see bold, see [stacktrace](http://#stacktrace) bellow.***

**microservice1** exposes 2 REST endpoints:

1. at root path for get request;
2. at /remote for get request.

`@RequestMapping("/")
public String home() {
    System.out.println("Hello Docker World " + 1);
    return "Hello Docker World " + 1;
}`

`@GetMapping("/remote")
public String remote() {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    return restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8080/maven-app2/", String.class);
}`

**microservice2** exposes 1 REST endpoint:

1. at root path for get request:

`@GetMapping("/")
public String home() {
    System.out.println("Hello Docker World " + 2);
    return "Hello Docker World " + 2;
}`

**Dockerfile for microservice1**

```
   FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
   VOLUME /tmp
   ARG DEPENDENCY=target/dependency
   COPY ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/lib /app/lib
   COPY ${DEPENDENCY}/META-INF /app/META-INF
   COPY ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/classes /app
   ENTRYPOINT ["java","-cp","app:app/lib/*","com.mhp.App"]
```

**Dockerfile for microservice2**

```
   FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
   VOLUME /tmp
   ARG DEPENDENCY=target/dependency
   COPY ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/lib /app/lib
   COPY ${DEPENDENCY}/META-INF /app/META-INF
   COPY ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/classes /app
   ENTRYPOINT ["java","-cp","app:app/lib/*","com.mhp.App"]
```

**docker-compose** file in microservice1:

```
version: "2"
services:
  microservice2:
    image: microsdocker2/maven-app2:latest
    expose:
      - 8080
    ports:
      - 0.0.0.0:8080:8080/tcp

  microservice1:
    image: microsdocker1/maven-app1:latest
    ports:
      - 0.0.0.0:8090:8080/tcp
    depends_on:
      - microservice2
    links:
      - microservice2
```

after building and installing each image I execute the `docker-compose up` and I get both applications deployed successfully and I can access the base root endpoint of each microservice.

```
...
    microservice1_1_2f0ac966a94e | 2018-11-26 14:26:08.955  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path '/maven-app1'
    microservice1_1_2f0ac966a94e | 2018-11-26 14:26:08.960  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.mhp.App                              : Started App in 6.63 seconds (JVM running for 7.358)


...
    microservice2_1_fa2376655f8c | 2018-11-26 14:26:08.090  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path '/maven-app2'
    microservice2_1_fa2376655f8c | 2018-11-26 14:26:08.101  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.mhp.App                              : Started App in 6.821 seconds (JVM running for 7.75)
```

stacktrace :

```
 microservice1_1_2f0ac966a94e | 2018-11-27 08:39:33.720 ERROR 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]      : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/maven-app1] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 404 null] with root cause
microservice1_1_2f0ac966a94e |
microservice1_1_2f0ac966a94e | org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 404 null
microservice1_1_2f0ac966a94e |  at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:94) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
microservice1_1_2f0ac966a94e |  at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:79) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
microservice1_1_2f0ac966a94e |  at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
microservice1_1_2f0ac966a94e |  at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:730) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
microservice1_1_2f0ac966a94e |  at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:688) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
microservice1_1_2f0ac966a94e |  at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:644) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
microservice1_1_2f0ac966a94e |  at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:296) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
```

> microservice1_1_2f0ac966a94e |  at com.mhp.App.remote(App.java:29)
>   ~[app/:na]

```
microservice1_1_2f0ac966a94e |  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
microservice1_1_2f0ac966a94e |  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
microservice1_1_2f0ac966a94e |  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
microservice1_1_2f0ac966a94e |  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
microservice1_1_2f0ac966a94e |  at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
microservice1_1_2f0ac966a94e |  at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
microservice1_1_2f0ac966a94e |  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
microservice1_1_2f0ac966a94e |  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:891) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
microservice1_1_2f0ac966a94e |  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
microservice1_1_2f0ac966a94e |  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
microservice1_1_2f0ac966a94e |  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
microservice1_1_2f0ac966a94e |  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
microservice1_1_2f0ac966a94e |  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
microservice1_1_2f0ac966a94e |  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
microservice1_1_2f0ac966a94e |  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
microservice1_1_2f0ac966a94e |  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
microservice1_1_2f0ac966a94e |  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
microservice1_1_2f0ac966a94e |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
microservice1_1_2f0ac966a94e |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
microservice1_1_2f0ac966a94e |  at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
microservice1_1_2f0ac966a94e |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
microservice1_1_2f0ac966a94e |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
microservice1_1_2f0ac966a94e |  at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
microservice1_1_2f0ac966a94e |  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
microservice1_1_2f0ac966a94e |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
microservice1_1_2f0ac966a94e |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
microservice1_1_2f0ac966a94e |  at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
microservice1_1_2f0ac966a94e |  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
microservice1_1_2f0ac966a94e |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
microservice1_1_2f0ac966a94e |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
microservice1_1_2f0ac966a94e |  at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
microservice1_1_2f0ac966a94e |  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
microservice1_1_2f0ac966a94e |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
microservice1_1_2f0ac966a94e |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
microservice1_1_2f0ac966a94e |  at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
microservice1_1_2f0ac966a94e |  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
microservice1_1_2f0ac966a94e |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
microservice1_1_2f0ac966a94e |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
microservice1_1_2f0ac966a94e |  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
microservice1_1_2f0ac966a94e |  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
microservice1_1_2f0ac966a94e |  at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
microservice1_1_2f0ac966a94e |  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
microservice1_1_2f0ac966a94e |  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
microservice1_1_2f0ac966a94e |  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
microservice1_1_2f0ac966a94e |  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
microservice1_1_2f0ac966a94e |  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
microservice1_1_2f0ac966a94e |  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
microservice1_1_2f0ac966a94e |  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
microservice1_1_2f0ac966a94e |  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
microservice1_1_2f0ac966a94e |  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
microservice1_1_2f0ac966a94e |  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_181]
microservice1_1_2f0ac966a94e |  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_181]
microservice1_1_2f0ac966a94e |  at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
microservice1_1_2f0ac966a94e |  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_181]
```

versions:

```
spring-boot version 2.0.5.RELEASE
docker version 18.09.0
docker compose version 1.23.1
```

Comment: Use service name `microservice1` or `microservice2` instead of `localhost`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use service name `microservice2` instead of `localhost`

```
@GetMapping("/remote")
public String remote() {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    return restTemplate.getForObject("http://microservice2:8080/maven-app2/", String.class);
}
```

https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

> By default Compose sets up a single network for your app. Each
>   container for a service joins the default network and is both
>   reachable by other containers on that network, and discoverable by
>   them at a hostname identical to the container name.